# Finding the values of $x$ that satisfy $\sin x+\sin2x+\sin3x+\cdots+\sin nx\le\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ for all $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, trigonometry

> If the exhaustive set of $x\in(0,2\pi)$ for which $\forall n$ the inequality $$\sin x+\sin2x+\sin3x+\cdots+\sin nx\le\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$ is valid is $l_1\le x\le l_2$, find $l_1$ and $l_2$.

Let $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \sin(ix)$=$S$ then I have managed to show that $$S=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{nx+x}{2}\right)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$$

I do not know what to do next. How can I handle the case for all $n?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think S must be $\frac{sin(\frac{nx+x}{2}).sin(\frac{nx}{2})}{sin\frac{x}{2}}$

Comment: @SisantaChhatoi my bad

Comment: @Shean maybe you entered the wrong function as I mistyped it... I've now corrected it...can you pls check it once again

Comment: Graphically, we must have $(l_1,l_2) = \left(\frac{2\pi}{3},2\pi  \right)$

Comment: @NN2 yes that's the correct answer ...can you pls prove it??

Comment: Fixed the equation: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zafxgvhllx . Again, there are multiple partitions...

Comment: The answer given by @NN2 could be considered correct for the limit of $S$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Put $n=1000$ into desmos to see.

Comment: @Shean ohh... actually the real question wasn't to find $l_1$ and $l_2$. The real question was to find the value of $\frac{3|l_1-l_2|}{2\pi}$ and the answer given is $2$. NN2's limit matches the computation asked so I thought his answer is correct

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad I just graphically observed these values. I haven't found the solution yet.

Comment: If rewrite formula as $\frac{\cos(x/2) -\cos((2n+1)x/2)}{2\sin(x/2)}\le \frac{\cos(x/2)+1)}{2\sin(x/2)}$, then solve this inequality $\frac{\cos(x/2)+1)}{2\sin(x/2)}\le \frac{1}{2}$. This is looking at the envelope of the curve family. Does this help?

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad I think you accepted and awarded a wrong anwser. See my comments below of this answer.

Comment: @NN2 oh damn... I didn't realise ....I also thought that the argument was correct....my bad...but what about his second answer?? Is that correct?

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad I haven't had time yet to look at his second answer but I will do later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $y=\frac x2$. Then $y\in (0,\pi)$, so $\sin y>0$ and $\cos\frac y2>0$. For each $n$ we have
$$S=\frac{\sin (n+1)y\cdot\sin ny}{\sin y}=\frac{\cos y -\cos(2n+1)y}{2\sin y}\le \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},$$
that is $$\cos y -\cos(2n+1)y\le \sqrt{3}\sin y,$$
$$\frac12 \cos y-\frac{\sqrt{3}}2\sin y\le\frac 12\cos(2n+1)y,$$
$$\cos\left(y+\frac{\pi}3\right)\le\frac 12\cos(2n+1)y$$
The latter inequality holds for each natural $n$ provided $$\cos\left(y+\frac{\pi}3\right)\le-\frac 12=-\cos\frac{\pi}3,$$
$$\cos\left(y+\frac{\pi}3\right)+\cos\frac{\pi}3\le 0,$$
$$\cos\left(\frac y2+\frac{\pi}3\right)\cos\frac{y}2\le 0,$$
that is when
$$\frac y2+\frac{\pi}3\ge \frac{\pi}{2},$$
$$y\ge \frac{\pi}3.$$

The remaining case $y<\frac \pi{3}$ was already considered in [D S's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4879653/finding-the-values-of-x-that-satisfy-sin-x-sin2x-sin3x-cdots-sin-nx-le-f/4882719#4882719).

Comment: A slight improvement: After $\cos(y/2+ \pi/3) \le -1/2$, you can say $\cos(2\pi/3) = -1/2$, and $cos$ is decreasing on $(2\pi/3, \pi)$, increasing on $(\pi, 4\pi/3)$, so the graph of $\cos$ on $(2\pi/3, 4\pi/3)$ remains below $-1/2$.

Comment: @DS I thought about this way, but finally decided to reduce the inequality to $\cos\left(\frac y2+\frac{\pi}3\right)\le 0$ to see the conclusion more clearly.

Comment: $$\cos\left(y+\frac{\pi}3\right)\le\frac 12\cos(2n+1)y$$
The latter inequality holds for each natural $n$ provided......can you pls provide a proof for this?

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad It follows from the inequalities $\cos\left(y+\frac{\pi}3\right)\le-\frac 12$ and $-\frac 12\le \frac 12\cos(2n+1)y$ for each natural $n$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Ohh I got it..thanks a lot..I'll give you the bounty after 6 hours (when the timer ends)

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Thanks. By the way, I provided a [new answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4879653/finding-the-values-of-x-that-satisfy-sin-x-sin2x-sin3x-cdots-sin-nx-le-f/4883138#4883138).  Whereas this answer is based on trigonometric transformations, the new answer is based on geometric intuition.

Comment: How do you have this?
-----

$$\cos\left(y+\frac{\pi}3\right)\le\frac 12\cos(2n+1)y$$
The latter inequality holds for each natural $n$ provided $$\cos\left(y+\frac{\pi}3\right)\color{red}{\le-\frac 12}=-\cos\frac{\pi}3,$$

Comment: @NN2 See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4879653/finding-the-values-of-x-that-satisfy-sin-x-sin2x-sin3x-cdots-sin-nx-le-f/4882748?noredirect=1#comment10414864_4882748) comment above.

Comment: @AlexRavsky I upvoted your comment just above because I thought the argument in the comment you mentionned is correct. But it's a mistake. I just realize that your argument is incorrect. It's incorrect to say  "
$$\cos\left(y+\frac{\pi}3\right)\le\frac 12\cos(2n+1)y \hspace{0.5cm}\forall n \implies \cos\left(y+\frac{\pi}3\right)\le-\frac{1}{2}$$ **because** $\frac 12\cos(2n+1)y \ge -\frac{1}{2}$"

Based on your argument, we can also argue that: "because $\frac 12\cos(2n+1)y \ge -5$ then $\cos\left(y+\frac{\pi}3\right)\le -5$"!

Comment: @AlexRavsky The best you can do is to say: because 
$$\cos\left(y+\frac{\pi}3\right)\le\frac 12\cos(2n+1)y \hspace{0.5cm}\forall n $$
then we must have
$$\cos\left(y+\frac{\pi}3\right)\le \cdot \inf_{\{n\in \mathbb{N}^+\}}\left\{\frac 12\cos(2n+1)y  \right\}$$

And you need to prove that $-1/2$ is really the infimum of $\left(\frac 12\cos(2n+1)y   \right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}^+}$ (for example: there exists a subsequence $(n_k)_k$ such that $\lim_{k\to +\infty}\left(\frac 12\cos(2n+1)y  \right) = -1/2$ for all $y\in [0,\pi]$. However, I don't think this statement is true.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

Proof that $x<2\pi/3$ does not work for all $n$. 
If $x \in (\pi/3, 2\pi/3)$, then for $n=1$, the statement is false. 
If $x \in (0,\pi/3)$, then for some $n$ such that $(n-1)x < \pi/3$ and $2\pi/3\ge nx \ge \pi /3 $, the statement is false.

It remains to show that the statement is true for $x \in [2\pi/3, 2\pi)$ (which was verified by some users graphically).

Answer (score 1):

*Whereas my [first answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4879653/finding-the-values-of-x-that-satisfy-sin-x-sin2x-sin3x-cdots-sin-nx-le-f/4882748#4882748) is based on trigonometric transformations, this answer is based on geometric intuition.*

When $x=\pi$ then for each natural $n$ the left hand side of the inequality equals $0$, so the inequality holds. So we assume that $x\ne\pi$.

Let $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N\cup \{-1,0\}}$ be a sequence of points of the plane $\mathbb R^2$ such that $z_{-1}=\left(-\frac 12,0\right)$, $z_0=\left(\frac 12,0\right)$, and for each natural $n$ the vector $\overline{z_{n-1}z_n}$ is the vector $\overline{z_{n-2}z_{n-1}}$ rotated counterclockwise by the angle $x$. Then the question is equivalent for which $x\in (0,2\pi)$ for each natural $n$ we have that the ordinate of $z_n$ is at most $\frac {\sqrt{3}}2$. It is easy to see that all points of the sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N\cup \{-1,0\}}$ belong to a circle $C$ containing the points $z_{-1}$, $z_0$, and $z_1$. Let $O=(x_O,y_O)$ be the center of $C$ and $R$ be radius of $C$. The point $O$ belongs to the middle perpendicular to the segment $z_{-1}z_0$, which is the ordinate axis, so $x_O=0$. Then $$\left(\frac 12\right)^2+y_O^2=|(0,y_O)-z_0|^2=R^2=|(0,y_O)-z_1|^2=\left(\frac 12+\cos x\right)^2+(y_O-\sin x)^2,$$ so $y_O=\frac {1+\cos x}{2\sin x}$ (we have $\sin x\ne 0$ because $x\ne \pi$) and
$$R=\sqrt{\left(\frac 12\right)^2+y_O^2}=
\sqrt{\frac 14+\frac {(1+\cos x)^2}{4\sin^2 x}}=$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{2\sin^2 x}}=\frac{\left|\cos\frac x2\right|}{\left|2\sin\frac x2\cos\frac x2\right|}=\frac 1{2\sin\frac x2}.$$
No point of the circle $C$ is higher that the horizontal line $L=\mathbb R\times \left\{\frac {\sqrt{3}}2\right\}$ when
$$\frac {\sqrt{3}}2\ge y_O+R=\frac {1+\cos x}{2\sin x}+\frac 1{2\sin\frac x2}=
\frac {\cos^2\frac x2}{2\sin\frac x2\cos\frac x2}+\frac 1{2\sin\frac x2}=$$
$$\frac {\cos\frac x2+1}{2\sin\frac x2}=
\frac {\cos^2\frac x4}{2\sin\frac x4\cos\frac x4}=\frac 1{2\tan\frac x4},$$
that is when $\tan\frac x4\ge\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}$. The latter holds iff $\frac x4\ge\frac{\pi}6$ iff
$x\ge\frac {2\pi}3$.

Now consider the remaining case $x<\frac {2\pi}3$. Then the circle $C$ cuts from the line $L$ the chord of length $$K=2\sqrt{R^2-\left(\frac {\sqrt{3}}2\right)^2}=\sqrt{4R^2-3}.$$
The point $z_n$ is above $L$ for some natural $n$ provided $K>1$. The latter holds iff
$R>1$ iff $\frac 1{2\sin\frac x2}>1$ iff $\sin\frac x2<\frac 12$ iff $\frac x2<\frac \pi6$ iff $x<\frac \pi3$.

Finally, if $\frac \pi3<x<\frac {2\pi}3$ then $\sin x>\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$, so the inequality fails already for $n=1$.

Concluding, we see that the inequality holds for all $n$ iff $x\in \left[\frac{2\pi}3,2\pi\right)$.